# I need a command that gives me the bluetooth profiles of a rooted android device over usb

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a rooted Android device and need to get a list of all the bluetooth profiles that are implemented. (preferably with profile version number as well)
Is there any command/tool that let me do this? I do not have an airsniffer so this will need to be a USB solution.

Normaly, the way to do this would be to look up the PICS, this is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boring answer to this question unfortunately seems to be: No, this is not possible to do unless using proprietary solutions and in that case it is vendor specific.